# Send an Array via a POST Message in Django

Tags: html, arrays, django, django-templates, django-views

I have an array of checkboxes.

```
{% for groups in groupList %}
    <tr>
        <td id="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check_{{groups.GroupID}}">
        </td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to pass this array (preferably by ID so I can get the GroupID in the view) in a POST message. I'm not sure how to send this data though. Is there any way of attaching an array to a form parameter? Or any alternative solution?

Comment: Make name attribute same as you make id attribute.
And you receive in `requiest.POST` only names of checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for groups in groupList %}
<tr>
    <td id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="groups" id="check_{{groups.GroupID}}" value="{{groups.GroupID}}">
    </td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In your views.py

```
groups=request.POST.getlist('groups')
```